# Red Hat <user> cannot register with any organizations. How to register?

Tags: rhel

So basically after I executed `subscription-manager register --username Username --password Password` I received a "Username cannot register with any organizations" error. 
I'm sure that the answer is in the Red Hat forums, but as I don't have a subscription I cannot view these forums.

Answer (score 4):

You just answered your own question. If you don't have a subscription, you can't register. Registering requires the use of a username / password pair that has at least one available subscription associated with it.

Comment: If it's for development purposes, the OP can get a free subscription on [Red Hat Developers](https://developers.redhat.com/).

Answer (score 3):

You must attach subscriptions to a system via Customer Portal using Red Hat Subscription Manager as the following steps:

1. Log-in to the Customer Portal
2. Click on the Subscriptions at the upper left

   [image]
3. Click on System in Subscriber Inventory under the Manage

   [image]
4. Click Register a system
5. After Registration, click on the name of the system in Units Panel
6. Click on Attach a subscription (written in blue letters)
7. Select the desired Subscriptions and click Attach Selected

Answer (score 0):

Even I was facing the same issue. But the problem got solved.
Until you accept the terms & conditions AND you have active subscription 1, you can't register. 
I have solved this problem by adding company name as N/A and job title as retired. After 2 days of creating the account, active subscription became 1 and I was able to register my system.

> https://access.redhat.com/products/red-hat-enterprise-linux/evaluation

go to this link and try to login for 30 days evaluation

Once I run the command :

> subscription-manager list --available

I got the following output:

```
 Subscription Name:   30 Day Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server Self-Supported
                     Evaluation
Provides:            Red Hat Beta
                     Oracle Java (for RHEL Server)
                     Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server
                     Red Hat CodeReady Linux Builder for x86_64
                     Red Hat Enterprise Linux for x86_64
                     Red Hat Ansible Engine
                     Red Hat Container Images Beta
                     Red Hat Enterprise Linux Atomic Host Beta
                     Red Hat Enterprise Linux Atomic Host
                     Red Hat Container Images
```